# Preview of ViewFlipper with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, viewflipper

In IntelliJ, I can preview a screen. If it is a ViewFlipper, it only shows the first page. Is there a way to preview all the pages of a flipper?

I can slightly modify the layout and preview each page, but I would like to preview them without touching the layout file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. You will have to switch views since you will only see the first `ViewFlipper` child.

I already filed a feature request and it is being considered, but no promises at the time: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123407

Comment: Thanks for requesting this feature!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to subclass `ViewFlipper` as follows:

```
public class MyViewFlipperextends ViewFlipper {

    private int displayedChild = -1;

    public FixedViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyViewFlipper);
        displayedChild = a.getInt(R.styleable.MyViewFlipper_displayedChild, -1);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        if (isInEditMode() && displayedChild != -1)
            setDisplayedChild(displayedChild);
    }

}
```

You need to add following to `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyViewFlipper">
    <attr name="displayedChild" format="integer"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Then I tried to switch displayed child in the preview by adding `app:displayedChild="1"`, but with no success: no child was displayed at all. I tried to put the logic in both `onFinishInflate` and `onAttachedToWindow`, with the same result.

I put it here so someone might find the problem here and find a much needed solution.

Comment: This worked for me with the latest version of Android Studio (3.5.1) as of writing this

Answer (score 0):

I found nice alternative solution: I make each page in a separate xml file. Than I include them all to main layout with `ViewFlipper`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/page1" />
    <include layout="@layout/page2" />
    <!-- ... -->

</ViewFlipper>
```

So I have preview for each page and not much code in main layout file.